# How can we view the whole spreadsheet instead of just the form in Google forms?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have been given a link to a Google docs form where I was supposed to enter some data. The URI looks something like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=foo
```

Is there anyway I can see the the responses already submitted by people using the 'foo' value (or may be some other hack like that)? Also, any idea how Google docs generates the keys?

Comment: I just realized that I answered your question as if you had asked something else. removed answer. +1 for good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were given the link but do not own the form, then no - responses are private unless the response spreadsheet is shared with you.

If the response spreadsheet was shared with you however, then you can just search for that document title in your Drive list, and it will appear as a normal shared document.

No idea how Drive generates document keys, but they are different between the spreadsheet and the actual form, again to make sure that the responses are private unless explicitly shared with others.